# Save photo in square format

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, cgrect, uigraphicscontext

I want to save a photo in the photo gallery that is in a perfect square. That extends to the full width of the screen. My code below position the image in what appears as a square but I dont know how to get the position perfect. I am just posting the code of the mask part. I am not putting my whole code. I am not having trouble saving the image.

[image]

```
@IBAction func mask(_ sender: Any) {
    let bottomImage:UIImage = UIImage(named: "backdropd")!
    let newSize2 = CGSize(width: bottomImage.size.width, height: bottomImage.size.height)
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize2, false, bottomImage.scale)

    if  let rightz:UIImage = rightImage.image{
        rightz.draw(in: CGRect(x: newSize2.width * 0.125,y: newSize2.height * 0.25,width: newSize2.width/1,height:   newSize2.height/2), blendMode:CGBlendMode.normal, alpha:1.0)
    }

    let newImage:UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    fullImage.image = newImage
}
```

Comment: Unless the image is not perfect square, two case can appear width>height (landscape image), width<height (potrait image). For instance say the image is potrait image, so height > width, in this case if you want to create a square you can crop the image in 3 way, 1. taking the top square portion, 2. taking the center square portion, 3. taking the bottom square portion. Which part you want to take as a square ?

Comment: Do you want your `rightImage` to be in square and centered in `bottomImage`?

Comment: @RatulSharker I want portrait and I dont want the image to be cropped. However if it must I want it cropped from the center.

Comment: In case you dont want to crop, there must be a gap, do you want to fill that gap with a static color or just crop from the center.

Comment: @RatulSharker I would like to fill the color with unicolor red.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you have to cut a square from the original image. Assume that the image is an `landscape` mode image. so `width > height`. So the resultant square image size would be `height * height`. Then draw the image according to you need with the background color red.

Following code is done for `landscape` image. For `potrait` images the task is same.

```
let image = UIImage(named: "image")!

        if image.size.width > image.size.height {
            // assuming the image is landscape one
            let sqrImgSize = image.size.height
            let extraPortion = (image.size.width - sqrImgSize) / 2
            let sqrPortionRect = CGRect(x: extraPortion,
                                        y: 0,
                                        width: sqrImgSize,
                                        height: sqrImgSize)


            // first of all, create the square image by cropping left right side out
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSize(width: sqrImgSize, height: sqrImgSize), false, 0.0);
            image.draw(at: CGPoint(x: -extraPortion, y: 0))

            let sqrImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext(); // here is your center cropped image
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext();


            // now if you are interested in filling the background with red, here it is
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(image.size, false, 0.0);
            let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
            context?.beginPath()
            context?.setFillColor(UIColor.red.cgColor)
            context?.move(to: .zero)
            context?.addRect(CGRect(origin: .zero, size: image.size))
            context?.closePath()
            context?.fillPath()
            sqrImage!.draw(at: CGPoint(x: extraPortion, y: 0))
            let sqrImageWithRedBackground = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

            imageView.image = sqrImageWithRedBackground
        } else {
            // do as above with slight calculation changes
        }
```

**Example**
[image]
Here the imageview with yellow background where content mode is set to aspect fit. So the background color of imageview is visible as the aspect ratio does not match.

**My output** 
[image]

**Explanation**
Clearly the purple color is the background color of `UIViewcontroller`'s `view` property. The yellow color is the background color of `UIImageView`. The Red portion is the filling color and at the center the image.

Hope it serves your purpose.

Comment: Great jobs Ratul. If I wanted to move my image slightly to the right by 50 pixels for the center, how would I do that?

Comment: add 50 to `extraPortion` in here `sqrImage!.draw(at: CGPoint(x: extraPortion, y: 0))`